# Uploading an Image object with GWT

Tags: gwt, blobstore

**So this is what i want to do.**

I have an Image object ( http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html ) and i want that uploaded to the Blobstore.

**So this is my problem.**

The formpanel i'm trying to use only works when the user actually supplies a file directory, so there is no way i can give an image adress to the form to upload like this:

blob:http://127.0.0.1:8888/6276f066-d415-45f4-984b-e0f98c542c50

**So my question is:**

How would i be able to upload an image from such a source to the blobstore.

Is it even possible?

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gwt's `Image` represents and `<image>` tag, which in turn represents an image loaded from server.

AFAIK, there is no way for javascript (and GWT) to get the data from `<image>` or `Image`, so consequentially it can not be uploaded.

Since the data for `Image` comes from server, why do you need to upload it back to server? If you are doing some selections, couldn't you just get the URL of the image and sent that to server?

Comment: Actually the Image comes from the html page itself and gets wrapped from a javascript object to a Image. it seems this problem is not easily solved with GWT, i've tried canvas but that also doesn't seem the solution. i've migrated my question to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911661/getting-urldata-from-an-image-as-a-blob and i'l accept your answer. I still appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: So you have an inline image in html? Such as `<img src='"data:image/gif;base64,R0l...'/>` ?

Comment: More like <img src='blob:http://127.0.0.1:8888/6276f066-d415-45f4-984b-e0f98c542c50'>