# Getting urldata from an image as a blob

Tags: javascript, html

**So this is what i want to do:**

I have an image blob and i need that converted to image data url.

**So this is my problem:**

```
<script> 
 document.body.onpaste = function(e) {
var items = e.clipboardData.items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  if (items[i].kind == 'file' && items[i].type == 'image/png') {
    var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
    var reader = new FileReader();
    document.write(reader.readAsDataURL(blob));
  }
}
 };
</script>
```

This returns an 'undefined'.

**So my question is**

How would i get the data url from that file.
My knowledge from javascript is VERY limited and there isn't very much to go on regarding html5 stuff.

Any and all help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself, it seems the reason I'm getting undefined is because the image isn't loaded when you call `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)`. I fixed this with:

```
reader.onload = function (event) {
  document.write(event.target.result);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Base64 encode the data and display it like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,[encoded data]">
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML

Comment: Yes, but to get that i need the data out of the blob first and that's proving difficult. because encoding the blob with window.btoa gives me [object blob], and the reader methods all give me undefined.